# Retrieve name from list stored in a json format type csv?

Tags: python, json, list, format

I have data in excel where the format of rows is json type as shown below:

```
[{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f95', 'gender': 2, 'id': 31, 'name': 'Tom Hanks', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': '/pQFoyx7rp09CJTAb932F2g8Nlho.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 15, 'character': 'Buzz Lightyear (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f99', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12898, 'name': 'Tim Allen', 'order': 1, 'profile_path': '/uX2xVf6pMmPepxnvFWyBtjexzgY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 16, 'character': 'Mr. Potato Head (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f9d', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7167, 'name': 'Don Rickles', 'order': 2, 'profile_path': '/h5BcaDMPRVLHLDzbQavec4xfSdt.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 17, 'character': 'Slinky Dog (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa1', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12899, 'name': 'Jim Varney', 'order': 3, 'profile_path': '/eIo2jVVXYgjDtaHoF19Ll9vtW7h.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 18, 'character': 'Rex (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12900, 'name': 'Wallace Shawn', 'order': 4, 'profile_path': '/oGE6JqPP2xH4tNORKNqxbNPYi7u.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 19, 'character': 'Hamm (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa9', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7907, 'name': 'John Ratzenberger', 'order': 5, 'profile_path': '/yGechiKWL6TJDfVE2KPSJYqdMsY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 20, 'character': 'Bo Peep (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fad', 'gender': 1, 'id': 8873, 'name': 'Annie Potts', 'order': 6, 'profile_path': '/eryXT84RL41jHSJcMy4kS3u9y6w.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 26, 'character': 'Andy (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fc1', 'gender': 0, 'id': 1116442, 'name': 'John Morris', 'order': 7, 'profile_path': '/vYGyvK4LzeaUCoNSHtsuqJUY15M.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 22, 'character': 'Sid (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb1', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12901, 'name': 'Erik von Detten', 'order': 8, 'profile_path': '/twnF1ZaJ1FUNUuo6xLXwcxjayBE.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 23, 'character': 'Mrs. Davis (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb5', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12133, 'name': 'Laurie Metcalf', 'order': 9, 'profile_path': '/unMMIT60eoBM2sN2nyR7EZ2BvvD.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 24, 'character': 'Sergeant (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb9', 'gender': 2, 'id': 8655, 'name': 'R. Lee Ermey', 'order': 10, 'profile_path': '/r8GBqFBjypLUP9VVqDqfZ7wYbSs.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 25, 'character': 'Hannah (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fbd', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12903, 'name': 'Sarah Freeman', 'order': 11, 'profile_path': None}, {'cast_id': 27, 'character': 'TV Announcer (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fc5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 37221, 'name': 'Penn Jillette', 'order': 12, 'profile_path': '/zmAaXUdx12NRsssgHbk1T31j2x9.jpg'}]
```

This represents actors with details like cast_id, character etc. in a movie. How do i retrieve all the actor names for this movie in python?

The output should look like:

```
'Tom Hanks', 'Tim Allen', 'Jim Varney' ...........
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

A straight forward list comprehension

```
js = [{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f95', 'gender': 2, 'id': 31, 'name': 'Tom Hanks', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': '/pQFoyx7rp09CJTAb932F2g8Nlho.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 15, 'character': 'Buzz Lightyear (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f99', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12898, 'name': 'Tim Allen', 'order': 1, 'profile_path': '/uX2xVf6pMmPepxnvFWyBtjexzgY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 16, 'character': 'Mr. Potato Head (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f9d', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7167, 'name': 'Don Rickles', 'order': 2, 'profile_path': '/h5BcaDMPRVLHLDzbQavec4xfSdt.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 17, 'character': 'Slinky Dog (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa1', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12899, 'name': 'Jim Varney', 'order': 3, 'profile_path': '/eIo2jVVXYgjDtaHoF19Ll9vtW7h.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 18, 'character': 'Rex (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12900, 'name': 'Wallace Shawn', 'order': 4, 'profile_path': '/oGE6JqPP2xH4tNORKNqxbNPYi7u.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 19, 'character': 'Hamm (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fa9', 'gender': 2, 'id': 7907, 'name': 'John Ratzenberger', 'order': 5, 'profile_path': '/yGechiKWL6TJDfVE2KPSJYqdMsY.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 20, 'character': 'Bo Peep (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fad', 'gender': 1, 'id': 8873, 'name': 'Annie Potts', 'order': 6, 'profile_path': '/eryXT84RL41jHSJcMy4kS3u9y6w.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 26, 'character': 'Andy (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fc1', 'gender': 0, 'id': 1116442, 'name': 'John Morris', 'order': 7, 'profile_path': '/vYGyvK4LzeaUCoNSHtsuqJUY15M.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 22, 'character': 'Sid (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb1', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12901, 'name': 'Erik von Detten', 'order': 8, 'profile_path': '/twnF1ZaJ1FUNUuo6xLXwcxjayBE.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 23, 'character': 'Mrs. Davis (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb5', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12133, 'name': 'Laurie Metcalf', 'order': 9, 'profile_path': '/unMMIT60eoBM2sN2nyR7EZ2BvvD.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 24, 'character': 'Sergeant (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fb9', 'gender': 2, 'id': 8655, 'name': 'R. Lee Ermey', 'order': 10, 'profile_path': '/r8GBqFBjypLUP9VVqDqfZ7wYbSs.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 25, 'character': 'Hannah (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fbd', 'gender': 1, 'id': 12903, 'name': 'Sarah Freeman', 'order': 11, 'profile_path': None}, {'cast_id': 27, 'character': 'TV Announcer (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024fc5', 'gender': 2, 'id': 37221, 'name': 'Penn Jillette', 'order': 12, 'profile_path': '/zmAaXUdx12NRsssgHbk1T31j2x9.jpg'}]
",".join([a["name"] for a in js])
```

**output**

```
'Tom Hanks,Tim Allen,Don Rickles,Jim Varney,Wallace Shawn,John Ratzenberger,Annie Potts,John Morris,Erik von Detten,Laurie Metcalf,R. Lee Ermey,Sarah Freeman,Penn Jillette'
```